# Mac Python Setuptools Installing in Wrong Directory

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, setuptools

Prior to today, executing `sudo python setup.py install` would install my desired module to `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/`. However, today it has been trying to install to `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`.

The only installs that occurred between these changes were Macports, updating Command Line Tools for Xcode, and OS X El Capitan update.

How can I change the default setuptools install path back to `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/`?

UPDATE #1

```
    $ which -a python
```

> /usr/local/bin/python
>
> /usr/bin/python

```
    $ echo $PATH
```

> /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin

UPDATE #2

I just ran `sudo /usr/bin/python setup.py install` and it successfully installed my module into `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/`. Now I just need to figure out how to to make `python` default to `/usr/bin/python`.

UPDATE #3

`python setup.py install` directs to the correct location, but permission is denied. Thus, `sudo python` directs to `/usr/local/Cellar/...`

UPDATE #4

By changing the order of paths in `/etc/paths`, I can force `sudo python` to use `/usr/bin/python` before trying `/usr/local/bin/python`.

Thanks all!

Comment: please add the output of `which -a python` and `echo $PATH` to your question.

Comment: I'm not sure if this may be related to [this post](http://superuser.com/questions/121407/python-easy-install-confused-on-mac-os-x)...?

Comment: Calling `sudo easy_install .` Installed the module in the correct directory. But I would still like to fix `sudo python setup.py install`.

Comment: IMO the cleanest way is adding `alias python='/usr/bin/python'` to your `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: @cel I added `alias python='/usr/bin/python' to my `~/.bash_profile` but that did not change anything. Setup.py install still directs to `/usr/local/Cellar/....`