# AWS ElasticBeanstalk CLI in OS X: EB Command Not Found

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am running into an error attempting to run the ElasticBeanstalk CLI tools on Mac OSX. I have been troubleshooting path issues and hope someone can shed some light. Here is my set up.

I am running Mac OS X El Capital 10.11.6, and I have manually installed Python 3.4 (via the download installer on python.org). I can see that it is installed correctly in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.frameworks/Versions`. Commands beginning with `python3` work as expected. I have also installed the the AWS ElasticBeanstalk CLI tools by running `sudo pip3 install --upgrade awsebcli` and can confirm it is located in the `/Users/myuser/Library/Python/3.4/lib/python/site-packages/` directory.

I have experimented with modifying my `~/.bash_profile`, as well as removing it. When I run `echo $PATH`, here is my output:

```
/Users/myuser/Library/Python/3.4/lib/python/site-packages/ebcli/:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python/site-packages:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bin:
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global/bin:
/Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/bin:
/bin:
/usr/sbin:
/sbin:
/opt/X11/bin:
/usr/local/git/bin:
/Users/myuser/.rvm/bin
```

Here is my `~/.bash_profile`

```
# Load the default .profile
[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" 

# Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
#[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

# Setting PATH for Python 3.4
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:${PATH}"

# Setting PATH for Python 3.4 site packages
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python/site-packages:${PATH}"
PATH="/Users/myuser/Library/Python/3.4/lib/python/site-packages/ebcli/:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

Comment: Can you paste the error as well? the `aws` command is not found at all?

Did you try to install it in a virtualenv with -p python3 to see if that's broken as well?

Comment: Also you should not add the site-packages in your PATH, those are libraries not (necessarily) binaries.

Comment: Thanks, Maresh! I had added that based on a couple of SO posts, like this one:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33302372/mac-python-setuptools-installing-in-wrong-directory

Which part should I take out? This line? 

`PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python/site-packages:${PATH}"`

or this one? 

`PATH="/Users/myuser/Library/Python/3.4/lib/python/site-packages/ebcli/:${PATH}"` 

Or both?

Comment: Also, to answer your first question, the error I get when I run `eb --version` is this: `-bash: eb: command not found`

Answer (score 32):

After a lot more trial and error, I finally got this working. Here are the steps I took.

1. Installed the **AWS CLI tools** for **Python 3+**.

   ```
   pip3 install awscli
   ```
2. Uninstalled the **EB CLI** for `/System/Library/Python`.

   ```
   pip3 uninstall awsebcli
   ```
3. Uninstalled the **EB CLI** for `/Library/Python`.

   ```
   pip3 uninstall awsebcli
   ```
4. Installed the **EB CLI** for `/Library/Python` with `pip`.

   ```
   pip3 install awsebcli
   ```
5. Removed the paths to the site packages directories from my `~/.bash_profile`.
6. Added the following to my `~/.bash_profile`.

   > ```
   > # Setting the path for Python 3.4
   > PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4:${PATH}"
   > export PATH
   > ```
7. Opened a new terminal window. (Can also run `source ~/.bash_profile`).
8. Changed into the project directory.
9. Ran `eb --version` and got the following output:

   ```
   EB CLI 3.9.0 (Python 3.4.4)
   ```

I realize it's uncool to post one's own answer, but hopefully my trial and error will be helpful to someone else with messed up paths.

Comment: No it's good that you post your solution. You can even approve it in a few hours and you get a badge for that :)

Comment: Thank you! In the third step, I think you meant `pip3 uninstall awsebcli` instead of `pip uninstall awsebcli`, that's what worked for me 

Comment: Seeing this answer, I tried uninstalling awsebcli, then installing the awscli, after which I reinstalled awsebcli. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 22):

This did it for me on Mac:

```
brew install awsebcli
```

From: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install-osx.html

Comment: Error: The following directories are not writable by your user:                                                                                                     
/usr/local/share/man/man8

Answer (score 10):

I faced the same problem. Just upgrading the awsebcli can help : `pip install --upgrade awsebcli`

Comment: Incredible that this worked like a charm. I just upgraded as you said and eb --version echoed. Thanks.

Comment: On Windows 10, eb --version resulted in "not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"; and this command *pip install --upgrade awsebcli* helped.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, I followed the instructions provided on [aws official doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install.html) and it worked.

1. `git clone https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup.git`
2. `./aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup/scripts/bundled_installer`
3. `echo 'export PATH="/home/<YOUR_USERNAME>/.ebcli-virtual-env/executables:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile && source ~/.bash_profile`

Then `eb --version` gave the expected output :

> EB CLI 3.15.3 (Python 3.7.2)

Answer (score 1):

Was having Zsh, this is what worked for me. Installed the latest python package from the main python website, and then:

```
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:$PATH
```

And setting the profile to

```
$ source ~/.zshrc
```

Installed, `pip3 install awscli` and `pip3 install awsebcli`

Check version to verify:

```
eb --version // EB CLI 3.12.4 (Python 3.6.4)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

**Homebrew Solution**

When upgrading to macOS Big Sur, my `eb` cli command stopped working. The shebang line in my `/usr/local/bin/eb` file was referencing an old version of python that got blown away with the os upgrade.

I upgraded and re-linked the `awsebcli` and all is now working again.

```
brew upgrade awsebcli
brew link --overwrite aws-elasticbeanstalk
eb --version
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
Do not run "pip install awsebcli --upgrade --user" when you install it for the first time! Run "pip install awsebcli" instead.

Steps to fix it:

- pip uninstall awsebcli;
- pip install awsebcli;
- pip install awsebcli --upgrade --user;

After all above steps "eb --version" should display the correct version with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

I get this warning when reinstall awsebcli:
*WARNING: The scripts eb and ebp are installed in '/Users//Library/Python/3.8/bin' which is not on PATH.*

In this case just add below path into your ~/.bash_profile is working fine.

```
export PATH=/Users/<you>/Library/Python/3.8/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In Sonoma macOS 14
Uninstall from pip if you did

```
pip3 uninstall awsebcli
```

And then

```
brew install awsebcli
brew link --overwrite aws-elasticbeanstalk
eb --version
```